# ngClass not working when changing condition in jQuery function

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm building a web application in Angular and I've been trying to dynamically change classes using the `ngClass` directive. However when updating the condition of the directive it doesn't always work.

I've tried updating the condition in a jQuery callback function when I'm scrolling, yet it does not work. However, when I change the condition's value via a function it works! I will give you the code below so you can understand what I'm talking about.

`navbar.component.ts`

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  stickyNavbar = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(() => {
      let scrolled = false;
      $(document).scroll(()=>{
        this.stickyNavbar = true;
        console.log(this.stickyNavbar);
      })
    })
  }
  public test() {
    this.stickyNavbar = true;
  }
}
```

`navbar.component.html`

```
<li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'dark': stickyNavbar, 'light': !stickyNavbar}" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
<li class="nav-item">
        <button class="btn nav-link" [ngClass]="{'dark': stickyNavbar, 'light': !stickyNavbar}" (click)="test()">Test</button>
      </li>
```

Normally, when I change `stickyNavbar` to `true`, `<li>` should get the `dark` class. This does not happen when scrolling the page, but if I press the button which calls the `test()` function it works and changes classes. If I call the `test()` function inside the jQuery `scroll()` function, it does not work. By the way, I'm using Angular 8.

EDIT: `*ngIf` doesn't work either.

Comment: why don't implement this with angular techniques?
Problem is that change detection does not work when the variable changes in jquery callback.

Comment: Ok thanks for the comment. I didn't suspect Angular wouldn't detect those changes on its own. Either way i forced a change detection with `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` and now it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't do this using jQuery. Instead, explain the problem you are trying to solve using jQuery and modify your question so we can help you figure out an Angular implementation for it. jQuery directly manipulates the DOM and won't fall well with Angular. This method might lead to more problems later on.

Comment: I tried doing this in jQuery because i was familiar with it. I haven't thought of an implementation in Angular because I wanted to see if it was possible in jQuery. I'm sure, however, that if I dig a bit, I can find the tools for an implementation in pure Angular and that's what I'm gonna try. Thanks for your help nonetheless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use jQuery (personally I don't like use jQuery and Angular, JQuery change the DOM, but you loose the view-model relation,futhermore Angular has enougth mechanics to avoid the use of jQuery), you need use ngZone. Angular don't know anything outside Angular

```
constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone){}
ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(() => {
      let scrolled = false;
      $(document).scroll(()=>{
        this._ngZone.run(() => { 
        this.stickyNavbar = true; 
         });
      })
    })
  }
```

But, in this case, you can use a simple HostListener

```
  @HostListener('document:scroll',['$event'])
  onScroll(event:any)
  {
        this.stickyNavbar = true;
  }
```

See a [demo in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qz8rqj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)